# Update chart form another Excel file

Tags: excel, charts, excel-2007

I have 2 Excel files. First with the chart (I'll name it chart.xlsm) and second with data for the chart (data.xlsm). The second file is connected by linking.

In first file I have a chart with axis numbered with date. When I open the file it ends with 2016-01. But when I open the second file (with "Open source" button) the chart updates and ends with 2016-03.

I looked into properties and,

Before opening the data.xlsm

```
Series values : =[0]!ATTs
Axis label range : =[0]!DatesValues
```

After opening data.xlsm

```
Series values : ='chart.xlsm'!ATTs
Axis label range : ='chart.xlsm'!DatesValues
```

The "Update values" option does not update the chart.
Is there a way to update this chart without having to open data.xlsm?

EDIT:
In chart.xlsm there is another sheet that takes data from data.xlsm. Difference is that another sheet takes single cells, not a range. And these values are updating, chart not.

Comment: specify the location of xlsm files

Comment: chart.xlsm is located on my computer, and data.xlms is located on network drive

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you are linking the chart to the data file, but I assume you are doing it via VBA, seeing that you are using xlsm.

The easiest way of getting what you want is to simply open chart.xlsx and data.xlsm, then create the chart and select the data you want to show from data. The downside of this solution is, that Excel will create a fixed link path to data.xlsm.

**EDIT** based on comment: Under "Data > edit links" you can edit the files Excel linked to. Sometimes in older versions these links used to break when the source file was open during creation (it wrote source.xls instead of \network_folder\source.xlsx, which would remove the ability to update data correctly if the source file was not open)

In that case edit the link manually and point it correctly to \\yourshare\yoursubfolder\sourcefile.xls

Comment: I think it is fixed now. In Data -> Edit links there is a link to data.xlsm. Then when I click "Open source", the file opens and the chart is updated. It is done through Excel itself. It is xlsm for another reasons.